# Change label javafx on keyboard input

Tags: javafx, actionlistener

I would like a javafx label to be automatically updated to what is being typed into a textfield, currently i have it changing only when enter is clicked. I am using a mix of swing and javafx.

is this possible?

thanks

```
exprField.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                fxLabel.setText(exprField.getText());

                        }
            });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Binding-Mechanism for this purpose.

```
  GridPane p = new GridPane();

    TextField tf = new TextField("DEFAULT");
    Label l1 = new Label("...");
    l1.textProperty().bind(tf.textProperty());
    p.add(tf, 0, 0);
    p.add(l1, 1, 0);
    Scene sc = new Scene(p, 500, 500);
    arg0.setScene(sc);
    arg0.show();
```

This code sets a textbox and a label into a gridpane. The text property of the label is bound to the text property of the textfield, which means as soon as the textfields changes, the text of the label gets updated according to whatever text is now in the textfield.

More information can be found here: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/binding/jfxpub-binding.htm